# SQL - Time Range (CASE WHEN)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a Time Query with the following logic. But I am not familiar with time query. Can anyone help?

```
CASE WHEN (07:00:00) TO (07:10:00) is between [STARTTIME] AND [STOPTIME] THEN 'YES'
```

Start Time and Stop Time are both DateTime Field

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL

Comment: Start Time ,Stop Time  is  Varchar or datetime?

Comment: @RohitPadma Sorry about that! StartTime & StopTime is DATETIME field.

Comment: Its okay . Hope the below Answer helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
CASE WHEN '07:00:00' >= [STARTTIME] AND '07:10:00' <= [STOPTIME] THEN 'YES'
```

if I understand clearly what you want to do.

Comment: This won't work for two reasons:                                                                                                                       1) You cannot use this condition as 07:00:00 greater than starttime and should be less than stoptime .                                                                                    2) time cannot be compared with  '>='

Comment: Yes that is true. You have to convert it to datetime with the current day before or convert it to timestamp.
Maybe you could use maketime() to compare them.

Comment: You cannot convert to current day - it would effect your comparison with starttime and stoptime.

Comment: What I meant was to convert to current day and convert StartTime and StopTime to date using the current day too. To convert two datetime eventually.

Answer (score 0):

HERE is the query :-  I used @start_Time(for STARTIME) and @end_Time (for STOPTIME) as local variable you can replace them. (As you said between i am taking in between those values if you need to include those time too then instead of > you need to put >= and same with < replace with <=).

```
 select CASE WHEN ((time_to_sec(timediff('07:00:00', time(@Start_Time))))>0 
           AND  (time_to_sec(timediff('07:00:00', time(@end_Time))))<0) 
    AND
        ((time_to_sec(timediff('07:10:00', time(@Start_Time))))>0 
           AND  (time_to_sec(timediff('07:10:00', time(@end_Time))))<0) =1 
           THEN 'YES' else 'NO' END
```

Hope it helps you !!